# Wondering what the word "geopolitical" refer to in the context

Tags: word-meaning

> Parliamentary approval of the pact would pave the way for greater economic integration between the two former geopolitical foes, by opening 80 of China's service sectors to Taiwan and 64 Taiwan sectors to China.

From [REUTERS](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/03/23/us-taiwan-protests-idUSBREA2M03220140323)

Based on my perception it has to do with "people of a country being enemy to the people of another country". I think when we say "two geopolitical foes" we do not mean that the two governments are enemies.  It means that this hostility has to with cultural differences.

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite: "geopolitical foes" means that their governments **are** enemies, but not their people. They don't fight with armies, or with economies, or even with culture; they fight each other politically, specifically in geopolitics (worldwide, international politics). It probably refers mainly to China (PRC) and Taiwan (ROC) fighting for recognition and support from other countries as the "real" government of China.

Answer (score 1):

Geopolitical refers to politics on a world scale.

The two countries mentioned, China and Taiwan, have definitely not been very friendly towards each-other in that area.

The expression *geopolitical foes* means that in the are(n)a of worldwide politics, the two parties are indeed, each other's enemies, or if you like a less string word, *adversaries*.

And no, it does not say anything about cultural differences, or military struggle for that matter. It says that *politically* they are on opposite sides.

"Countries" here means "the governments of the countries", by the way. In the area of international politics, it is not uncommon that a country's government takes a stand that is different from what many members of the population think. It is very well possible that my country (the Netherlands) politically disagrees to the point of being enemies with say, Greece, but that does not necessarily mean the Dutch and the Greek population are enemies.